# If statement with buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

so I have a problem.
Im trying to make a program with buttons, so you could choose something with buttons.
Im running python 3.

I made the buttons, customized them, everything is good with the buttons.

```
def choiceFirst():
    choice = 1
    buttonPressed = True

def choiceSeco():
    choice = 2
    buttonPressed = True

window = Tk()
window.title("Title lol")
icon = PhotoImage(file='download.png')
window.geometry("300x215")
window.iconphoto(True,icon)

button1 = Button(window,
                text="Choice 1",
                command=choiceFirst,
                font=("Arial", 20),
                fg='#00f000',
                bg='white',
                relief=RAISED,
                bd=10,
                padx=20,
                pady=20,
                activeforeground='#00f000',
                activebackground="white",)
button2 = Button(window,
                text="Choice 2",
                command=choiceSeco,
                font=("Arial", 20),
                fg='#00f000',
                bg='white',
                relief=RAISED,
                bd=10,
                padx=15,
                pady=15,
                activeforeground='#00f000',
                activebackground="white",)

button1.pack()
button2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Now I want to add an if statement. Something like

```
if buttonPressed:
   if choice == 1:
      print("choice 1 code here")
   elif choice ==2:
      print("Choice 2 code here")
```

I tried adding that, it just doesn't work :(

All help is apreciated!

Comment: in your choiceFirse/Seco functions you're trying to change `choice` - but at this point, those are local variables. Add `global choice, buttonPressed` as first line in those functions to make those variables global and change them globally

Comment: Also, you're in window's main loop. You could, you know, actually put that `"choice 1 code here"` in choiceFirst function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry for bad english) You have to put the actions of the buttons in their functions.

Try this:

```
def choiceFirst():
    print("choice 1 code here")

def choiceSeco():
    print("Choice 2 code here")
```

and just remove the if statement.

Comment: Ohhhh, Im stupid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can find an example here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-disable-enable-a-button-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Remove the nested `if/else` statement.

Edit: @Dinux. Thank. I didn't realise.

Easier way to do is write **one function** instead of **two(2) functions** by using `if/else` block statement.

Add keyword `command` for `lambda` for both `Button` widgets.

Also you use f-string format

snippet:

```
def choiceFirst(num):    
    if num == '1':
        print(f"choice {num} code here")
    else:
        print(f"choice {num} code here") 

 

button1 = Button(window,
                text="Choice 1",
                command=lambda: choiceFirst('1'),
                ...)

button2 = Button(window,
                text="Choice 2",
                command=lambda: choiceFirst('2'), 
                ...)
```

Comment: The ‘match’ statement was introduced in Python 3.10. It won’t work on versions < 3.10